# Numbers after whitespace doesn't send in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to make a bank system for a game I'm developing. The issue is with whitespace and I have tried out $.trim(); without any success.

This is my Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#money_in").click(function(){
        $("#error").empty(); // empty error div
        $("#success").empty(); // empty success div
        
        var money = $('#number_bank').val(); // get value from input field
        
        $.post("app/banken/banken_sett_inn.php",
            {
            money: money
            },
            function(output, res, status){
                if (~output.indexOf("ikke")){ // if output contains 'ikke'
                    $('<span>' + output + '</span>').appendTo('#error');// add text to error feedback
                    $("#error").show(); // show error feedback
                } else {
                    var money_in_bank = parseInt(<?php echo AS_session_row($_SESSION['ID'], 'AS_bankmoney', $pdo) ?>) + parseInt(money);
                    var money_on_hand = parseInt(<?php echo AS_session_row($_SESSION['ID'], 'AS_money', $pdo) ?>) - parseInt(money);
                    
                    $('<span>' + output + '</span>').appendTo('#success'); // add text to success feedback
                    $("#success").show(); // show success feedback
                    $('#saldo').text(numberWithSpaces(money_in_bank) + ' kr'); // Edit numbers for bank
                    $('#saldo_top').text(numberWithSpaces(money_in_bank) + ' kr'); // Edit numbers for top container
                    $('#saldo_left').text(numberWithSpaces(money_on_hand) + ' kr'); // Edit numbers for left container
                    
                    $("#number_bank").val(''); // Empty input field
                }
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php

ob_start();
include_once '../../includes/dbh.php';
include_once '../../auth.php';
include_once '../../functions/functions.php';

$money = remove_space($_POST['money']);

if(isset($money)){
    $number = $money;
    if(number_valid($number) && $number <= AS_session_row($_SESSION['ID'], 'AS_money', $pdo)){
        echo "Du satt inn ".number($number)." kr i banken";
    } else {
        echo "Du kan ikke sette mer penger i banken enn du har på hånden";
    }
}

?>
```

My issue is when I input `10 000` into my numbers-field, it only adds `10` on example `#saldo` even though it should add `10 000`

I have experimented with removing whitespace on `var money` with `$.trim();` but it still won't work. It does edit my database with the correct amount. If I have `10 000` in my bank and I deposit `10 000` it says `20 000` in my database, but the feedback on the site only says `10 010`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$. trim()` function to remove spaces from the beginning and end of the specified string. The spaces in your string are in the middle. So it would work.

try to use replace

```js
money.replace(/\s/g, '')
```